# Pygame wrongly detects joystick that isn't there

Tags: python, pygame, tablet

I have a strange problem with pygame
I have no joystick connected to my laptop but `pygame.joystick.get_count()` returns 1
It even detects axis inputs. The devices connected to my computer are: mouse, keyboard and a wacom intuos.

No other USB devices are connected.
EDIT:
I have made the following test script

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
print("joystick count:",pygame.joystick.get_count())
gJoystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
gJoystick.init()
print(gJoystick.get_init())
fGetEvent = True
while fGetEvent:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("joystick button pressed")
            fGetEvent = False

gJoystick.init()
print(gJoystick.get_numaxes())
```

When I press a button on my intuos tablet, it registers as a joystick button press. Do I have to disconnect my tablet to make this work properly?

Comment: Have you tried isolating your inputs? Try removing USB devices one at a time and rerunning pygame.joystick.get_count() until you get 0

Comment: I have run a test script. It seems that it detects my wacom intuos as a joystick. I am not sure how to stop that from happening though. Will make edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a plethora of programs, python included, detect wacom tablet inputs as joystick inputs. You just have to unplug it.

Comment: I have a similar situation in Android with my Galaxy S23 Ultra. It looks like the digitalizer is detected as a Joystick which y-axis is always activated downwards.